# Attain value present in earlier set but missing in later set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I can't get my head around why this is so difficult to achieve!

All I want to do is retrieve a value from an *earlier* set of results that does not exist in a *later* set of results from within the same table.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
select b.Id
from table a
where
    not exists
        (select b.Id from table b where b.Id = a.Id and
        b.time = (select max(time) from table where time < a.time))
```

I know this is not syntactically correct, the difficulty is accessing the `b.Id` while maintaining a reference to the other set's `time` and it's an issue in every form I've tried, such as using `except`. I've also tried outer joins to the same table to try to find the missing Id but to no avail.

I found it easy to find the Id of a missing row present in the later set and not the previous, but not the other way around.

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2.

**EDIT**

This is hard to pen so I'll give an example:

### Table

```
- PK - Id  - Time
------------------
- 1  - 100 - 13:00
- 2  - 99  - 13:00
- 3  - 100 - 11:00
- 4  - 99  - 11:00
- 5  - 98  - 11:00
- 6  - 100 - 10:00
- 7  - 99  - 10:00
- 8  - 98  - 10:00
- 9  - 97  - 10:00
```

So the result I expect would be rows:

{ 5, 98, 13:00 } and { 9, 97, 11:00 } as thse IDs are missing from the set that comes before. Note the time is from the later set, to show that they're missing from *that* set of time.

Comment: Lee I would suggest some sample data and desired results which I am sure you probably know given your reputation. It will help everyone visualize what you want.  Next if you can do the inverse find missing later record post that code we can help you try to flip it

Comment: It would be helpful if you put together a 3 row example with desired output. (jinx @matt)

Comment: Thanks I've updated my question to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: What if (3  - 100 - 11:00) is removed ?

Comment: @Serg in that case it would be in the result set too as the Id of 100 would be missing compared to its earlier set grouped by 10:00

Comment: See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing this with `group by` and `having`.  If I understand correctly:

```
select t.id
from table t
group by t.id
having max(t.time) < @LaterTime and 
       sum(case when t.time >= @EarlierTime then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: Sorry I've tried to explain as best I can but there is no "static" time. It's based on each set of rows and the set of rows preceding it based on time, which is why I've used max yet lesser than in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use table variables.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (column1, column2, column3)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (column1, column2, column3)

SELECT INTO @table1 (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES
FROM IntendedTable
WHERE Date < DesiredDate

SELECT INTO @table1 (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES
FROM IntendedTable
WHERE Date > DesiredDate

SELECT * 
FROM @table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @table2)
```

The above isn't syntactically correct, but it would likely be the approach I would take.

Comment: The thing is there is no static desired date. I have many rows grouped by time and I need to know which rows are missing from each "pair" of sets, from the later one to the one just before, if you see what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Ids having exactly one time, the first one

```
select * 
from table
where id in (
  select t1.id 
  from table t1
  group by t1.id
  having count(distinct t1.time) = 1 )
 and time = (select min(t2.time) from table t2)
```

**EDIT**
Following OP comments, all missing rows above min time for the id

```
  select  id,time
  from (
     select t1.id,t2.time
     from
      (select distinct id from table ) t1
     cross join 
      (select distinct time  from table) t2     
     except
      select distinct id,time
      from table     
   ) tt  
   where time > (select min(t3.time) from table t3 where t3.id=tt.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. Gives expected result.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (PK INT , ID INT , [TIME] TIME)

INSERT INTO #T
SELECT 1 ,100 , '13:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ,99  , '13:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 3 ,100 , '11:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 4 ,99  , '11:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 5 ,98  , '11:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 6 ,100 , '10:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 7 ,99  , '10:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 8 ,98  , '10:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 9 ,97  , '10:00'

;WITH R
AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY T1.TIME DESC) RANK,*
    FROM #T T1
)

SELECT DISTINCT R1.PK, R1.ID, R2.TIME 
FROM R R1
INNER JOIN R R2  ON R1.RANK = R2.RANK + 1  
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT ID, TIME  FROM R R2 WHERE R1.RANK = R2.RANK + 1  AND R1.ID = R2.ID 
)
```